# laravel migrations messed up cannot roll back or reset

Tags: laravel-5

so I went to create some migrations of some tables 
and was hitting the up arrow and changing the --create"name" but was leaving the class name the same on accident after I already created some I noticed and tried renaming the files and classes but ran into problem I migrated and got errors I tried renaming them back and resseting and rolling back but everything is too messed up I dropped the tables manually and when I try to reset or rollback now I get a table does not exist error is there any easy way to get out of this mess with out having to create a new project?

Comment: just decided to make a new clean project from scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you mess up your migrations (can happen if you have migrated and change directly in the migrations), you can always just drop all tables and run a fresh `php artisan migrate`.

It sounds like you had migrated, and changed the tablenames of some tables. When you do that and try to rollback (reset starts out with rolling back) it tries to drop the tables, but when it gets to the changed tablename it can't find it in the database and you get an error saying the table doesn't exist :)